# Select xml node by attribute name ignoring namespace of that attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a node like this:

```
<meta name="og:description" content="Here's the content" />
```

I want to be able to select this element if the name is "description" whether it's in a namespace or not. I need to be able to select the meta tag if it's name is "og:description", "description", "blah:description", etc.

I've seen resources for xpath that show how to select within a namespace, but not irrespective of a namespace.

Comment: `og:name="description"` is namespace, but `name="og:description"` is just namespace-looking-like content, isn't it?

Comment: @abatishchev yes, you're right. I had the same reaction. 
Based on the accepted answer (which uses `[ends-with(@name, 'description')]`), apparently OP wanted to filter on "namespace-looking content". Based on the highest-voted answer with `[local-name()="description"]`, you're right, other people want to filter on namespaced attribute name itself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using XPath 2 you could do:

```
 /meta[ends-with(@name, 'description')]
```

For XPath 1 we need:

```
 /meta['description' = substring(@name, string-length(@name) - string-length('description') + 1)]
```

Comment: This is obviously not a correct solution, as this selects only a top element `meta`. Also the `meta` top element will be selected even when the attribute name is `Mydescription`, `yourdescription`, ..., `whateverdescription`, Just noting these facts for the readers. Not downvoting!

Answer (score 16):

**Use**:

```
//meta[@*[local-name() = 'description']]
```

This selects all `meta` elements in the XML document that have an attribute with local-name `"description"`.

By definition, the standard XPath function **[`local-name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-local-name)** produces the name of the node from which the namespace prefix (if any) is stripped off.

If, on the other side you need to select a `<meta>` element the string value of whose `name` attribute is either `"description"` or any string that ends with `":description"`, use this XPath 1.0 expression:

```
//meta
   [@name = 'description' 
  or substring(@name, string-length(@name) - 11) = ':description']
```

**Do note**:  Always avoid using the `//` pseudo operator if the structure of the XML document is statically known. Often using `//` causes slow execution.